# Camera.Parameters.setRecordingHint and aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-camera

I've found some odd behavior around [Camera.Parameters.setRecordingHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRecordingHint%28boolean%29) that I'd like to understand better.

If I set it to `true`, the size of the preview image can come back different from what I pass to [setPreviewSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewSize%28int,%20int%29).  It depends on what size I set it to-- some aspect ratios work and some don't.

See the screenshots below-- `setPreviewSize` has been set to 640x480 for both, but one has setRecordingHint to `true` and the other to `false`.  I have the code that produces this effect [on GitHub](https://github.com/paleozogt/AndroidCameraExample).

Is this expected behavior?  The docs for [setRecordingHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRecordingHint%28boolean%29) don't indicate anything like this.

[image: comparison of front-facing camera on S4 with setRecordingHint true/false]

Comment: I can confirm this exact issue on LG G3 (Android 4.4.2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set `video-size` parameter to the correct value. I had the same problem - preview size was `640x480` and the preview appeared stretched while using `setRecordingHint(true)`. I then used `getParameters().flatten()` to print out all parameters set for my `Camera` device. My `video-size` parameter was actually set to `1920x1080` causing the incorrect aspect ratio. You can change this parameter using `params.set("video-size", "WxH")`. Only then is the aspect ratio correct.

Comment: is `"video-size"` documented anywhere?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I actually had to set all 3 sizes (preview, picture and video) to the same values to have it working properly on a Samsung S4 :/
This is really weird and not documented at all!

Comment: Note that it may not work to set "video-size" if it is not an approved resolution in the "video-size-values" list.

Answer (score 0):

i've seen a lot of random behavior around this and it unfortunately depends on the oem as well. i see a difference in framerate as well on some phones, like nexus 4 preview framerate drops in half. we depend on the preview frame callback to come at our desired framerate so we have to switch it on phone model unfortunately.

Comment: In fact on the MotoG running 4.4.2 this totally breaks video recording. You can record perhaps a single video but if you try to prepare the media recorder to record again using the the preview surface freezes and recording hangs.

Comment: I can confirm that on Nexus 4 (Android 5.0), the framerate breaks in half when disabling the recording hint. However, on many other devices it does not reduce the framerate at all (including the LG G3).

Comment: our joke around the office is that the hint is to not setRecordingHint