# Camera2 aspect ratio on Samsung

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm using the Camera2 API on an S5, showing a TextureView-based preview at 720x480.  With Camera1, the preview looks fine, but with Camera2 its distorted:

[image]

I'm calling `SurfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize` properly, etc.  This seems to work fine on non-Samsung phones.

Curiously, if I modify [Camera2Basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhpTq.png) to use the front-facing camera and 720x480 it has the same distortion:

[image]

Any idea what may be behind this problem?  It seems [reminiscent of another Samsung aspect ratio problem I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054170/camera-parameters-setrecordinghint-and-aspect-ratio) but I'm not sure how to translate that work-around over to Camera2.

Comment: Hi! the same problem. have u find any solution?

Comment: For LG G3 updating from Android 5.0 to 6.0 fixed the issue.